# return type nodiscard function and void function definition

Tags: c++, function, boolean, void

If I have a version of a function that returns a `bool`, I want to have a version of the function that doesn't return a `bool`. I tried `nodiscard` around the function definition but it didn't allow for both definitions.

Are functions returning booleans the same speed as functions returning void?
If not then is there a way to declare a void and a bool version of a function?

Comment: You can't overload a function solely based on return type. If your goal is to have something like `[[nodiscard]] bool myFunction()` and `void myFunction()` and for the compiler to decide which one is called based on whether you use the return value or not... You would need some other way to distinguish those functions, and maybe explain a little more about what's motivated you to try this approach in the first place.

Comment: You can't have two overloaded functions that vary only by return type.  It costs nothing to return a boolean that gets ignored.

Comment: Well im not quite sure about how function calls work behind the scenes but i just figured in general if you dont utulize the variable the compiler could benefit from choosing the correct output. It seems obvious what the correct output to me should be. But i dont know what the compiler does. or if a void function still returns a value we just dont see.
Wish the compiler knew when i wanted to return a void version of a function.
Like with the standard vector emplace back it returns a iterator. When i was using push back it returned void so i could just return that function in a void function.

Answer (score 5):

> are functions returning booleans the same speed as functions returning void?

The overhead of assigning a value to a `bool`, and discarding a `bool` return value, is infinitesimal to the point of not being noticeable.  So, essentially, yes for all practical purposes.

> is there a way to declare a void and a bool version of a function?

Functions can't be overloaded on return value alone.  You would have to either use separate function names:

```cpp
bool myFunctionWithResult()
{
    ...
    return ...;
}

void myFunctionWithoutResult()
{
    myFunctionWithResult();
}
```

```cpp
void doSomething()
{
    bool result = myFunctionWithResult();
    // use result as needed...
}

void doSomethingElse()
{
    myFunctionWithoutResult();
}
```

Or else give one of them an output parameter:

```cpp
void myFunction(bool &result)
{
    ...
    result = ...;
}

void myFunction()
{
    bool ignored;
    myFunction(ignored);
}
```

```cpp
void doSomething()
{
    bool result;
    myFunction(result);
    // use result as needed...
}

void doSomethingElse()
{
    myFunction();
}
```

In which case, you could simplify that into a single function:

```cpp
void myFunction(bool *result = nullptr)
{
    ...
    if (result)
        *result = ...;
}
```

```cpp
void doSomething()
{
    bool result;
    myFunction(&result);
    // use result as needed...
}

void doSomethingElse()
{
    myFunction();
}
```

Needless to say, for a `bool` (or any other primitive type), this is needlessly complicated.  Just `return` the `bool`/primitive normally, and let the caller discard the value if it wants to.  This kind of micro-optimizing only really matters if the output is a more complex type, say a class with dynamically allocated members, where returning an instance actually invokes overhead that you may need to avoid at times.